# Django FormView Not Redirecting on Subclass

Tags: django, class, subclass

I have been trying to get back into the flow of OO programming. When I create an UploadServerInventory class and upload a file I get redirected back to root. However when I create UploadServerInventory and upload a file I get a "UploadServerInventory didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Shouldn't I be inhering everything from the parent class? It looks like I am passing everything back up to the Super class? What fundamental problem am I missing?

```
class UploadExcelFile(FormView):

    template_name = 'cmdb/upload.html'
    form_class = UploadFileForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(UploadExcelFile, self).form_valid(form)

    def set_excel_file(self):
        self.excel_dict = self.request.FILES['file'].get_book_dict()

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(UploadExcelFile, self).form_invalid(form)


class UploadServerInventory(UploadExcelFile):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.set_excel_file()
        super(UploadServerInventory, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(UploadServerInventory, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the return statement in your subclass `form_valid` method.

Note, the definitions of both `form_valid` and `form_invalid` in UploadExcelFile are completely pointless. There's no point overriding a method only to call the superclass version.

Comment: There isn't a wall thick enough for me to bang my head against at that simple oversight. Thanks!